# How to keep multiple directories using Webpack Clean?

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to keep multiple directories using [Webpack clean](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputclean):

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  output: {
    clean: {
      keep: /ignored\/dir\//, // Keep these assets under 'ignored/dir'.
    },
  },
};
```

I've tried the following:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  output: {
    clean: {
      keep: /ignored\/dir\//, <- this directory is cleaned
      keep: /ignored2\//, // <- this directory is ignored from clean
    },
  },
};


// I've also tried passing them in as an array.
```

Is there a way to do this?